# python - open all plain text files in a directory with ".dta" extension and write lines to csv

Tags: python, parsing

I have a number of plain-text config files (.dta) that are spread through 27 sub-directories. I am trying to parse some information from all of them into a common document that is easier to work with.

Thus far I have:

```
import linecache
import csv
import os

csvout = csv.writer(open("dtaCompile.csv","wb"))

directory = os.path.join("c:\\","DirectKey")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".DTA"):
        f=open(file,'r')

        lines = f.readlines()
        description = lines[1]
        articleCode = lines[2]
        OS = lines[25]
        SMBIOS = lines[32]
        pnpID = lines[34]
        cmdLine = lines[28]
        csvout.writerow([SMBIOS, description, articleCode, pnpID, OS, cmdLine])
        f.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
   f=open(file,'r')
   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '000003APP.DTA'
```

Comment: Consider using [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    f=open(file,'r')
```

Your probaby need

```
    f=open(os.path.join(directory, root, file),'r')
```

file is just the name of the file, and doesn't say anything about the path to it. you have to use os.path.join with the various components to create the full path

Answer (score 0):

```
if file.endswith(".DTA"):
    file = os.path.join(directory, root, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
f=open(file,'r')
```

Try:

```
f = open(os.path.join(directory, file), "r")
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the directory you're program is executing in is not the same as the directory you're walking.

Try printing:
    os.getcwd()
to see.